# When I try to run my GUI on netbeans it says that there are no available classes what can I do about that?

Tags: java, netbeans, mainclass

When I run my GUI on netbeans a little window pops up saying "available classes:" but there aren't any when there clearly is a class and it has a main. Could you please help me.

```
public class connectFour extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public connectFour() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Generated code    

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new connectFour().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by trying to carry out a **Clean & Build** on your project. To do this either select the **Clean And Build** toolbar button [image] or access the NetBeans Menu Bar and select: **Run** then the **Clean And Build Project** menu items. Look for any Compile errors within the NetBeans Console Window. If the compilation was successful then try to run your application.

If your are still having problems then......

Is this the **only class** in your application? If **not** move your mouse pointer into the NetBeans **Projects** pane and again, with your mouse pointer, right-click on the title of your project (let's say it's **ConnectFour**) then from the drop-down menu select **Properties**.

In the Project Properties dialog window that is displayed select **Run** located within the **Categories** pane on the left. Now in the right side of the Project Properties dialog window you can see a text box labeled **Main Class:**. Make sure it indicates: ***packageName*.ConnectFour** class, if not then select the [image] button located to the right side of the text box and from the displayed **Classes List** dialog, select the desired startup class and select the [image] button. Select the **OK** button located at the bottom of the Project Properties dialog then try to run your application.

Comment: First when I try to Clean and build a window shows up saying available classes and there aren't any. Then when I got to the Project Properties dialog window the text box Main Class isn't there